# Is it possible to set a SFDC proxy for a force.com sites page?

Tags: force.com-sites

Has anybody ever called an external server from a Force.com site using jQuery.ajax()? The following code works on a normal visualforce page (via apex pages) but not on a visualforce page running on my Force.com site. Does anybody know why? I'm guessing it should be the proxy.

```
var json = JSON.stringify({"id":"1","method":"test"});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://c.cs8.visual.force.com/services/proxy",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    data: json,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('SalesforceProxy-Endpoint', url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "OAuth " + '{!$Api.Session_ID}');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-User-Agent', 'salesforce-toolkit-rest-javascript/' + 'v24.0');
    },
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        console.log("SUCCESS", response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, e){
        console.log("ERROR", e);
    }
});
```

Comment: It works from a visualforce page but not from a site because it is restricted by the javascript cross-domain policy.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the proxy endpoint relatively so that it uses the correct domain name, eg:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: UserContext.siteUrlPrefix + '/services/proxy',
  ...
})
```

Further, can you confirm you are accessing it through your Site's URL, not just `/apex/pageName`?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I'm trying to access it through my Site's URL and doesn't work.

I know that using JavaScript Remoting would work, I was just wondering if there was a way where I can make it work just using JavaScript

Comment: Thanks @user2722 - the code in question (`https://c.cs8.visual.force.com/services/proxy`) is _not_ the Site URL... maybe you could take a screenshot of the request dump in Chrome's network tab?